# In my spring mvc plus restful i am getting 406 error

Tags: java

```
@RestController
public class WelcomeController { 
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  @Path("first")
  @RequestMapping(value="/welcom" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody ModelAndView modelAndView() {
    String msg="hello spring welcome";
    return new ModelAndView("helloWelcome","message",msg);
  }
```

It's spring mvc + rest code in maven. it throws `406 status error`.
how can i call the same method through rest and mvc controller.

Comment: why are you using `@ResponseBody` if you are having a view?

Comment: i need to return the response through @ResponseBody ,it binds the response

Comment: then just return String msg object instead of `ModelAndView`